# How to use Plutus chain index with real testnet

Tags: plutus-pab

I would like to use Plutus API for getting script datum (datumFromHash) but how to setup and run Plutus chain index on testnet or main net?

I saw there are methods in Plutus.ChainIndex.Types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use this tool to run everything you need: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-pab-executables/pab-cli. You probably don't need the PAB or wallet backend, so for just a node and chain-index you can run e.g. `pab-cli testnet remotewallet`

Comment: Thank you. I got the point. One more question. Could you please give a hint how to use/deploy contracts in the case of full usage of PAB( node & chain index in my case.
I want to sign on client side !

Comment: Not easy to summarise. Best to look at examples such as the integration test, see https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-pab-executables/examples